# how to break a line in RStudio

Tags: rstudio

New to R, and have trouble with RStudio but not with R GUI when typing a long code.

R GUI allows me to break the line of code when pressing `Enter` by adding `+`
e.g.

```
>rolldice <- function (){
 + dice <-1:6
 + rolldice <- sample (x=dice, size=2)
 + sum (rolldice)
 }
```

However, in RStudio, it autocompletes part of the code when I try something like below

```
>rolldice <-function (){}
```

I tried to add additional codes within the bracket but somehow could not break the line by `Enter`. `Enter` would end the function, not adding additional lines with `+`. Thus I am stuck with either
(when not pressing `Enter`)

```
>rolldice <- function (){dice<1:6 rolldice <- sample(x=dice, size=2) sum(rolldice)}
```

which is considered an error code by RStudio

or
when pressing `Enter` to attempt to create a line breaker, which gives me the following

```
>rolldice <- function (){}
>
```

Surprisingly googling this (e.g. RStudio line breaker) did not yield any solution. One suggestion was to add `n` , but I have no clue what `n` is (obviously I tried the alphabet, but it was wrong).

I know I must have missed some piece of relevant info on the internet or in a book, since this is one of the most rudimentary issues in learning a new language.

Any help?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add anything in the brackets to break a line in the example of that function. Pressing `Enter` should work just fine. RStudio will simply move down the code until it gets to the end parenthesis. The `n` thing you mentioned I've used in strings to introduce a break using `\n`.

Comment: You can also try a `;` (semicolon) between each command and leave them on the same line, as in `{dice <- 1:6; rolldice <- sample(x=dice, size=2); sum(rolldice)}`.

Comment: @hensen. Thanks a lot! 'Enter' somehow doesn't work like I stated in my posting, it ends the function. ';' is accepted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @B Chen I've had that issue in the past too, where the function was being cut off at the end of the line. Try restarting your RStudio session. That has helped fix the issue for me.

Comment: @akrun Could you explain the role of the double curly brackets in `{{expr}}`, please ?